# How to use https to call the kubernetes api server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-security

I have a two node kubernetes cluster on a linux server and I use the kubernetes api to pull stats about them using a http api through kubeproxy. However I haven't found any good documentation on how to use https. I am kinda new to setting up environments so a lot of the high level documentation goes over me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure https on kubernetes api server. You can check Kelseys's https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way

Also look at this doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/accessing-the-api/

Configuring kubernetes SSL manualy may be hard. If you have troubles try to use kubeadm utility - https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/